# load and run another .py file in wxpython GUI

Tags: wxpython

Have written script for GUI using wx python. All i need is to load another python file and run with option of  providing inputs(values)  to variables of python file using GUI. And display the python file results.
I was able load file need to run....

Comment: I gave an answer but I'm not sure if it answers your question as it's not very clear. An example of what you've tried and what isn't working would help us out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from my [GooeyPi application.](https://github.com/multiphrenic/GooeyPi) It is a GUI front-end to PyInstaller. It runs the `pyinstaller.py` code with some flags and sends the output to a `textctrl` widget. It uses `wx.Yield` to avoid locking up the interface, although moving the code to its own thread is another option.

```py
class GooeyPi(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GooeyPi, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        # Results go in here. Read only style so people can't write in it.
        self.txtresults = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(420,200),
                                      style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)


    def OnSubmit(self, e):
        ...
        # getflags returns something like ['python.exe', 'pyinstaller.py' '--someflag' '--someotherflag']
        flags = util.getflags(self.fbb.GetValue())
        logging.debug('calling subprocess {}'.format(flags))
        for line in self.CallInstaller(flags):
            self.txtresults.AppendText(line)               

    def CallInstaller(self, flags):
        ' Generator function, yields on every line in output of command 
        p = subprocess.Popen(flags, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while(True):
            retcode = p.poll()
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            wx.Yield() # Prevent GUI from freezing
            yield line
            if(retcode is not None):
                yield ("Pyinstaller returned return code: {}".format(retcode))
                break
```

And my getflags function for reference. It uses `sys.executable` to find the path to the python binary file and `os.path.join` to find the path to the python script to run. Then it appends a number of flags based on my config file. The resulting list is then returned.

```py
def getflags(fname):
    flags=[]
    flags.append(sys.executable) # Python executable to run pyinstaller
    flags.append(os.path.join(config['pyidir'], 'pyinstaller.py'))
    if config['noconfirm']:
        flags.append('--noconfirm')
    if config['singlefile']:
        flags.append('--onefile')
    if config['ascii']:
        flags.append('--ascii')
    if config['windowed']:
        flags.append('--noconsole')
    if config['upxdir'] != '':
        flags.append('--upx-dir=' + config['upxdir'])
    if pyversion(config['pyidir']) == 2.1:
        flags.append('--distpath=' + os.path.dirname(fname))
    else:
        flags.append('--out=' + os.path.dirname(fname))
    flags.append(fname)
    return(flags)
```